# LaTeX-related events

Tags: latex-misc

[Someone](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389/promoting-tex-latex-and-friends/395#395) mentioned a TUG meeting in UK, so I though we can try to keep something of a calendar/dashboard for new and upcoming events. Probably no better way of promoting these to new members.

I suggest the following template:

- **What?** Event name, organizing entity
- **When?** Dates and/or times
- **Where?** Address, driving directions if necessary. A link would probably work fine as well.
- **Who?** Notable individuals/guests, or a profile of the expected audience (if applicable). Mention event fees payable by participants.
- **Why?** Topic/agenda of the meeting, if any.

This is community wiki, so feel free to step up and edit to your heart's content. A one-entry-per-event requirement is probably self-evident.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps voting for this question could work a bit different --- if someone plans to attend a certain event, upvote it. How does that sound?

Comment: If I would attend I would tell it by commenting instead of anonymously. How about voting if we believe attending that event is very recommendable? This may also help to decide to go there.

Comment: I'll post something about the UK-TUG AGM once the detail is actually agreed.

Comment: I would love to see how this list could be ever kept up to date.

Comment: Upvoting won't work well for the purposes of this thread, because highly voted events will continue to be most highly voted once the event is finished.  We could try to delete past events, but has its own problems.

Answer (score 3):

- **What?** [4th international ConTeXt meeting](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010)
- **When?** 13.9.2010 - 18.9.2010, from Monday evening to Saturday afternoon. See the [online program](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010/programme.shtml) for details
- **Where?** [Brejlov](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010/location.shtml), Czech Republic (close to Prague)
- **Who?** ConTeXt users, developers and other interested people. Registration is still open, all-in fees are 300 Euro for LUG members.
- **Why?** The ConTeXt meetings started because typical TeX (EuroTeX, TUG) conferences are often expensive to attend, tend to focus on LaTeX, and are too formal for our taste.

Comment: +1 for typical TeX conference are too formal for our taste :-)

Answer (score 3):

The TeX Users Group maintains a calendar for TUG and EuroTeX conferences: http://tug.org/meetings.html

And TUGboat prints a calendar each issue: http://tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb31-1/tb97calendar.pdf

Answer (score 2):

DANTE is maintaining an online [calendar](http://texcalendar.dante.de/year.php) of TeX events, but it is little known and therefore not always up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

- **What?** [Autumn conference of DANTE e.V.](http://www.dante.de/events/mv43.html), the german TeX users group
- **When?** 25.9.2010 - 26.9.2010, additional meeting the evening before
- **Where?** University of Trier, Fachbereich II / Germanistik, Universitätsring 15, 54296 Trier. [How to get there](http://www.dante.de/events/mv43/Anreise.html).
- **Who?** Mainly members of DANTE e.V.
- **Why?** See [conference program](http://www.dante.de/events/mv43/Programm.html) in German.

[DANTE e.V.](http://www.dante.de) was founded 1989 in Heidelberg and supports TeX users in Germany. DANTE subsidizes the German CTAN server and hosts a German FAQ. There's a [DANTE edition](http://www.lob.de/?flag=dan) of TeX books.

Answer (score 1):

- **What?** [TeXperience 2010](http://pavel.striz.cz/texperience/), the annual Czechoslovak TeX User Group meeting.
- **When?** 16.9.2010-19.9.2010, from Thursday evening to Sunday afternoon.
- **Where?** [Brejlov](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010/location.shtml), Czech Republic (close to Prague)
- **Who?** Czech and Slovak TeX Users.
- **Why?** See the [online program](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2010/programme.shtml) for details. Fees are 140 Euro all-in for LUG members, 160 otherwise.

This meeting overlaps partially with the 4th ConTeXt meeting, and is held at the same venue.
ConTeXt meeting participants can stay for TeXperience as well for an extra 40 Euro.

Answer (score 1):

- **What?** UK TeX Users' Group AGM and Speaker Meeting
- **When?** Saturday 26.10.2011, AGM at 2 pm, speaker day details still
  being finalised
- **Where?** Trinity College, Oxford
- **Who?** TeX Users in the UK
- **Why?** UK-TUG has a yearly AGM, and this is a rare opportunity to
  meet other TeX users in the UK.

More details on the group website: http://uk.tug.org/.